# Why my render has that black area? If in the viewport shading view looks fine? Rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I added an additional (not finished) render in cycles where the plane has a glass material and the figures are sticking out in the bottom whereas in the viewport shading doesn't look like that.

Thanks

[image: viewport shading]

[[image: render cycles][2]]

[image: viewport shading glass plane looks ok]

[image: render cycles figures sticking out of the plane]

Comment: Hello, maybe overlapping faces? (Z fighting)

Comment: @moonboots I have some figures touching each other but they are not overlapping and the figures are not sticking out at the bottom.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/